# Why I can't get access to the /api/auth/user in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to get access to the /api/auth/user, but I am still getting "401 Unauthorized".
How can I set my SecurityConfiguration? I can't use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in my project.

There is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/antifraud/transaction").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody String name, @RequestBody String username,
                                          @RequestBody String password) {
        if(StringUtils.isBlank(name) || StringUtils.isBlank(username) || StringUtils.isBlank(password)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }

        return userService.registerUser(name, username, password);
    }

}
```

Comment: please enable spring security DEBUG or TRACE logs and edit your post and include them IN FULL. Since i dont do guesswork coding and you should always include debug logs and learn how to debug your application before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `"401 Unauthorized"` because you haven't authenticated the `"/api/auth/"` endpoint.
try the modified version,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").authenticated() // <-- Authenticate here
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/antifraud/transaction").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

If still getting the same error then try with below method,

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/api/auth/user").permitAll() // Allow access to /api/auth/user without authentication
                        .antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/antifraud/transaction").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(Customizer.withDefaults()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, It has not helped. I am still getting 401.

Comment: I updated answer can you try it.

Comment: Still no. Maybe I should add hasAuthority()?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

add two more asterisk before

```
.requestMatchers("/**/api/auth/**/").permitAll()
```

*EDIT*
Use `antMatchers` instead of `requestMatchers` with csrf() disabled

```
http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests( auth -> auth
                        .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/api/antifraud/transaction").authenticated()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

                ) .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(Customizer.withDefaults()));
```

Comment: No, it has not helped, I got 500 and "2023-07-08T16:33:12.184+02:00 ERROR 10342 --- [io-28852-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element"

Comment: I have edited my answer please check the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy/paste your code and it work very well, maybe problem is in your request what you try to do:
[image: result]

And one more detail please use `@RequestParam String name...` instead of `@RequestBody String name ...` or create a custom object like User(name, username, password) and pass them to the request with `@RequestBody User user`